# error in my SQL syntax wont allow inserting into table

Tags: mysql, datetime

im trying to write a very (supposedly) simple piece of code which puts data into my database.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `clubevent` (clubevent_id ,club_id ,event_id ,theme_id ,clubevent_date ,clubevent_start_time ,clubevent_finish_time ,clubevent_cost) VALUES (NULL ,  $clubstate,  $eventstate,  $themestate,  $datestate,  $sTimestate,  $fTimestate,  $coststate)";
```

however i am constantly getting a message that

> Error: INSERT INTO `clubevent` (clubevent_id ,club_id ,event_id ,theme_id ,clubevent_date ,clubevent_start_time ,clubevent_finish_time ,clubevent_cost) VALUES (NULL , 4, 14, 2, 2016-04-26, 23:00:00, 05:00:00, 05)
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':00:00, 05:00:00, 05)' at line 1

the data im attempting to get into this is:

> 4, 14, 2, 2016-04-26, 23:00:00, 05:00:00, 05

can anybody shed some light on the issue?

Comment: You have a quoting error. Use a prepared statement and you won't have this problem.

Comment: I agree, use a prepared statement to resolve. That being said, the reason your having issues is because your date/times are not escaped. Its reading the semicolons as break, causing errors

Comment: If this is sql server why do you tag as mysql?

Comment: This is your typical [failure to escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) that means you've got [SQL injection problems](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you're not familiar with the basics a guide like [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com) should help clarify a few things and help you avoid mistakes like this in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  clubevent (clubevent_id ,club_id ,event_id ,theme_id ,clubevent_date ,clubevent_start_time ,clubevent_finish_time ,clubevent_cost) VALUES (NULL , ' $clubstate',  '$eventstate',  '$themestate',  '$datestate',  '$sTimestate',  '$fTimestate',  '$coststate')";
```

Comment: i get another (very similar) error now. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''clubevent_id' ,'club_id ,event_id' ,'theme_id' ,'clubevent_date' ,'clubevent_st' at line 1"

Comment: Those should be backticks (`) not single quotes (')

Comment: Sprinkling quotes through this doesn't magically fix problems, it just hides them, even if it seems like the obvious fix. As two other people have observed, prepared statements will 100% fix this if used correctly. Use `?` or names like `:clubstate` if PDO is an option to represent the data.